# Proving the convergence of the sequence $\sum \limits _{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\sin (n)}{n}$ with comparison test

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

I need proving that the sequence $\sum \limits _{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\sin (n)}{n}$ converges with comparison test.

---

I have seen a lot of questions that are really like this question, but I haven't found an answer using only a comparison test. I need to do that in the most elementary way, without Dirichlet's test, Abel, Fourier, complex trigonometric identities, but just with comparison test. Is it possible? if so I will be glad to hear from you how. Thanks a lot!

Comment: This series converges but it does not converge absolutely. A comparison test will not work.

Comment: The comparision test only applies to sequences whose terms are all $ \geq 0$. There are "elementary" ways of proving that this converges without appealing of the concepts you mentioned.

Comment: @user oh you right, so there isn't another way without using Abel's test, and Dirichlet's test? because I want to prove that with the most elementary tests.

Comment: Let $S_n = \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{\sin(k)}{k}$ be the partial sum. Consider the finite sum $S(N+n)-S(N)$. Apply Abel's transform (discrete version of integration-by-part) on it and conclude that $S(N+n)-S(N)$ is small whenever $N$ is large.

Comment: @DannyPak-KeungChan I can't use  Abel's test

Comment: I did not use Abel's test. I just derive everything from nothing.

Comment: The discrete version of integration-by-part is completely elementary. There are only finitely many terms and the concept of limit is not involved.

Comment: @DannyPak-KeungChan you said apply Abel's transform, and I haven't learned that yet. I can't use integration, but only series rules.

Comment: Forget the name "Abel's transform". For the finite sum $\sum_{k=1}^n a_n b_n$, write $B_n = \sum_{k=1}^n b_k$, $B_0=0$, and $b_n = B_n - B_{n-1}$. Express the finite sum in terms of $a_n$ and $B_n$ only.

Comment: This is the discrete version of integration-by-part.

Comment: This is perhaps the most straightforward with an integral test. You can show that the integral
$$\int_1^\infty \frac{\sin x}{x}\mathrm{d}x$$
Converges using a Laplace transform.

Comment: @K.defaoite the integral test requires that $\frac{\sin(x)}{x}$ be monotonically decreasing, and it isn't.

Comment: @K.defaoite I haven't learned integration. So I can't use any sentences related to integration, such as the integral test.

Comment: @AlannRosas Oh, fair point. It's been a while since I did real analysis.

Comment: I can use the ration test, the root test...

Comment: I don't think you can use standard convergence tests here I am afraid

Comment: @Riemann'sPointyNose can you elaborate more about the reasons which don't let us use standard convergence tests?  In my opinion is because we don't have tools to prove that the sequence/sum is positive. Is it right?

Comment: @Riemann'sPointyNose thank you!!!

Comment: @aasc232 I just realised I made a mistake in my comment - the absolute value version of the sum is clearly not ${\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n}}$, it's ${\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{|\sin(n)|}{n}}$ of course, but what I was trying to say is that we cannot really do much with this useful. To avoid confusion, I am going to delete my comment and repost it fixed to avoid confusion

Comment: @aasc232 exactly yes. In fact - the terms in the sum are not all positive, and are not all negative, and the sum doesn't "alternate" nicely. So we cannot use any convergence test that uses a positive sum, and cannot use alternating series test either (since it does not alternate). One other idea would be to show the sum converges absolutely, which would prove it converges conditionally too, but this also does not work since the absolute value version of the sum is ${\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{|\sin(n)|}{n}}$, which isn't any easier. So we cannot draw any conclusion here using "basic" tests

Comment: @Riemann'sPointyNose Are there any chances that we can apply the basic Cauchy's sequences test? because I can see that if we pick a big, enough, value of $n$, then we can see that for each $p\in \mathbb{N}$ the following: $\sum \limits_{i=n+1}^{n+p}\frac{\mid \sin (n) \mid}{n}<\varepsilon$ holds, because of the negative values.
***
* Is what we said in the previous comments, that the absolute value actually diverges, is the reason why we can't use Cauchy's sequences test either?

Comment: @Riemann'sPointyNose Note that I meant to write the absolute value onto the whole sequence, and not for each element separately.

Comment: @Riemann'sPointyNose Maybe you haven't noticed, so I'm tagging you again.